# How to change the column in core table in magento 2

Tags: database, frontend, magento2.2, setup

I need to change the existing column (title to be null) in review_detail table in Review module in magento.Please provide me a solution

Comment: changing the column mean you want alter the table, ex. column name A to B ?

Comment: No, I need to alter the title field to be null

Answer (score 6):

You can Modify the definition by upgrade script as below.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

/**
 * Upgrades DB schema for a module
 *
 * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    if ($installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists('table_name', 'column_name')){
        $definition = [
            'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Comment'
        ];
        $installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
            $setup->getTable('table_name'),
            'column_name',
            $definition
        );
    }
}
}
```

**Note:** I would suggest you not to change the definition of column of core table, in your case you can pass the empty string as title which should work.

Comment: Thank you, But it is failed to add review,It shows the exception as We can\'t post your review right now.

Comment: this is because magento checking the title and throwing the exception, changing the definition won't make any deference.

Comment: unable to get you, Then what should I do, Am I need to mention upgraded version??

Comment: If i modified in my DB table by mannually it works fine, But need to modify definition by programmatically

Comment: then try this it will change the definition.

Comment: No, It does not make any change in DB

Comment: to make this script run you need to change the version of your module (in which this upgrade script is) or delete you module row from `setup_module` table then upgrade

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Recurring Script which execute every time when upgrade command run:**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace Module\Review\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
    
    class Recurring  implements InstallSchemaInterface
    {
    
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if ($installer->getConnection()->tableColumnExists('review_detail', 'title')){
            $definition = [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Title'
            ];
            $installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
                $setup->getTable('review_detail'),
                'title',
                $definition
            );
        }
    }
 }
```